# When I use mongoose & connect MongoDB, I can insert and get data. But unable to find data using MongoClient

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My code as follows. Open localhost/users/,brower return

```
{"_id":"55519446e063d4c409f93f00","username":"justnode","__v":0}
```

but when I open mongo shell and input: use `student` and `db.student.find()`,I can't find anything. My MongoDB version is `3.0.1` and nodejs version is `0.12.2`, OS is `Centos 6.4`

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/student', function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
   username: {type: String, unique: true}
});

var UserModel = mongoose.model('UserModel', UserSchema);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));  

/*
  post content as follows
  {
    "username": "justnode"
  }
 */
app.post('/users/create', function (req, res) {
  console.log("in /users/create");
  var userModelJson = req.body;
  var userModel = new UserModel(userModelJson);

  userModel.save(function(error) {
    if(error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.json({msg: "error"});
    }
    console.log("user created: " + userModel.username);
    res.json(userModel);
  });
});
/*
open localhost/users/  brower return {"_id":"55519446e063d4c409f93f00","username":"justnode","__v":0}]
but when I open mongo client: db.student.find()  i can't find  anything
 */
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
  UserModel.find({}, function (err, docs) {
      res.json(docs);
  });
});

var serverApp = app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + serverApp.address().port);
});
```

Comment: can you add the steps you are trying in the post to connect through mongo shell (i assume mongo client you mean is mongo shell)

Comment: Make sure you are connecting to *student* db on mongo client. **show dbs** then **use student**.

Comment: isn't  db.UserModel.find() in your case according to what you defined ???

Answer (score 0):

Change database(student), schema(UserSchema) and model(UserModel)'s name and try it again. My case, after changing the variable's name and restart, it works. (I've no idea why, maybe mongoose or mongo shell has some bug?)